# Google analytics does not work on android

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-tabactivity

I want to import google analytics on my android application and my codes is

```
private GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo);

    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.startNewSession(getString(R.string.analytics_id), this);
    tracker.trackPageView("/demo");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    tracker.stopSession();
}
```

but it is not working... where am I doing wrong? Thanks...
Note: I used tabactivity and each of tab codes like that...

Comment: Do you have internet privileges?

Comment: yes i have, indeed copy code from sample code

Comment: You have to wait approx. 24 hours to see the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer from this blog. Hope it's helpful.
http://blog.blundellapps.com/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I had done right but found to be wrong.  Replace “-” with an “en dash” character (–, &&;#8211;) ?

Comment: The replacement of "-" with "en dash" worked for me. Also, instead of fetching key from string.xml i passed raw string in tracker.startNewSession() function. Hope it help others.

Answer (score 0):

To Setup

//  Add libGoogleAnalytics.jar to your project's /libs directory.

//    Add the following permissions to your project's AndroidManifest.xml manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**EDIT:**
In order to use Google Analytics, you must be signed in with a registered Google Account email address and password.

Create a [Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount) here. However, just having a Google account does not automatically grant you access to Analytics. First, you must r[egister for Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/sign_up.html), a one-time, simple process.

Comment: can you tell what is not working? what kind of exception you are facing.

Comment: just check statistic from http://www.google.com/analytics/ but no value... i do not know why?